# Select a valid choice.[<selection>]is not one of the available choices. Error

Tags: python, django, modelform

What I want is multi-selected anwsers chosen to be saved and submitted to DB

However I get this error on each of the questions.

**my models.py**

```
class preferences(models.Model):
    cuisine = (
        (1,u'Italian'),
        (2,u'American'),
        (3,u'French'),
        (4,u'Japanese'),
        (5,u'Russian'),
        (6,u'Chinese'),
        (7,u'Mexican'),
        (8,u'Indian'),
        (9,u'Middle Eastern'),
        (10,u'Thai'),
        (11,u'Spanish')
    )
    vegeterian = (
        (1,u'Yes'),
        (2,u'No'),
        (3,u'I appreciate both')
    )
    lunch = (
        (1,u'Cafe'),
        (2,u'Restaurant'),
        (3,u'Fast Food'),
        (4,u'Takeaway'),
        (5,u'Grocery/Lunch Box')
    )
    dinner = (
        (1,u'Inexpensive Restaurant'),
        (2,u'Fine Dining'),
        (3,u'Takeaway'),
        (4,u'Fast Food'),
        (5,u'Delivery'),
        (6,u'Cooking at home'),
        (7,u'Cheeky Bar') #Make it with a hint that having a dinner w/ a cheeky pint

    )
    Friday = (
        (1,u'Bar'),
        (2,u'Night club'),
        (3,u'Karaoke'),
        (4,u'Netflix & chill'),
        (5,u'Video games'),
        (6,u'Cinema'),
        (7,u'Theater'),
        (8,u'Restaurant'),
    )

    weekend = (
        (1,u'Hiking'),
        (2,u'Sport activities'),
        (3,u'Attending sport events'),
        (4,u'Music events'),
        (5,u'Art/Science exhibitions'),
        (6,u'Chilling at the park'),
        (7,u'Video games'),
        (8,u'Cinema'),
        (9,u'Theater'),
        (10,u'Chilling at home')
    )

    UserID = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='User', null=True,default='')
    cuisine = models.ManyToManyField('self',choices=cuisine, max_length=20,blank=False,default='')
    cuisine_extra = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    vegeterian = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=vegeterian)
    lunch = models.ManyToManyField('self',choices=lunch,max_length=20,blank=False,default='')
    dinner = models.ManyToManyField('self',choices=dinner,max_length=20,blank=False,default='')
    Friday = models.ManyToManyField('self',choices=Friday,max_length=20,blank=False,default='')
    weekend = models.ManyToManyField('self',choices=weekend,max_length=40,blank=False,default='')
```

Here I use `M2Mfield` as we are storing multiple items and use it on the same `model('self')`.

**modelform.py**

```
class preferencesForm(ModelForm):

    """def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(preferencesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)"""


    class Meta:
        model = preferences
        fields = ['cuisine', 'cuisine_extra', 'vegeterian', 'lunch', 'dinner', 'Friday', 'weekend']
        widgets = {
            'cuisine':forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            'lunch':forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            'dinner':forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            'Friday':forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            'weekend':forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        }

form = preferencesForm()
```

I tried doing it with `__init__`, that didn't help either. and at this point I was lost.

**views.py**

```
def display_form(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = preferencesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.UserID = request.user
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = preferencesForm()
    return render(request,'display.html',{'form':form})
```

**views.py** should be fine, but just in case.

The error looks like this

> Select a valid choice. [u'3', u'9'] is not one of the available
>   choices.

(the selection depends on the number of a selected choice, but the idea is the same)
I also tried changing integers to a string, didnt help either.
Also tried `[u'1']` etc, didn't work either.

I know I can use a **multiselectfield** library, but that would be bad for my database, since storing multiple instances is not a very good idea.
I have seen that there are quite a few similar errors, but none of them helped me :/
Would greatly appreciate your help! Thanks!

The error [image: error]

Comment: do we really need *all that code* to debug this?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I just posted this just in case, since I can't really figure out what exactly is causing the problem

Comment: yeah but how many people do you think are going to be willing to go through it?

Comment: well, I would gladly shorten it out, if I would know what exactly do I cut from here, guess templates are removable but idk about other stuff

Comment: How about telling us which line raises the Error at least??

Comment: The form would not submit whatsoever, the error raises at the page itself( will apply screenshot now)

Answer (score 0):

Your fields make no sense. A many-to-many field is a relationship between models, where each side can have multiple items. It is not a set of items from a list of choices.

You should use CommaSeparatedIntegerField, with the [`validate_comma_separated_integer_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.validate_comma_separated_integer_list%60) to validate that the items are integers.